# PyQt6 Overly Large Program Scaling

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

After recloning from git, all of a sudden my PyQt6 program is scaled weirdly. Many, but not all widgets are overly large.

[Example of overly large text in the main QMenuBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BkS3.png)

[Example of overly large text in a QDockWidget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGYPK.png)

I've inserted the following so that my pyqtgraph PlotItems scale consistently across monitors of different resolutions, but with/without this code the scaling issue persists.

```py
QApplication.setHighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy(
    Qt.HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy.PassThrough
)
if platform.system() == "Windows":
    if int(platform.release()) >= 8:
        ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(True)
```

I don't think this has to do with having an overly high resolution display, as some text (tab names, for example) are the proper size.

I've also created a new virtual environment and reinstalled libraries.

```
pyqtgraph~=0.13.1
PyQt6~=6.4.0
PyQt6-sip
PyQt5
PyOpenGL

numpy==1.23.5
```

Some other things of note:

- I'm not using stylesheets to modify my font size/QFont anywhere explicitly.
- Sometimes running it from terminal vs pycharm solves the problem, but not always. It is strange that there's an inconsistency here, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Let me add that this bug only arises when running from PyCharm--when running from window's console the sizing is normal.

Comment: "I don't think this has to do with having an overly high resolution display": yes, it does. You probably have a high DPI setting or are using font scaling; finding the real cause of your issue is a different story, especially considering the context of PyCharm, which might create inconsistencies with its own default settings. Are you using stylesheets with font properties, or do you set font sizes explicitly in your program? (Note: please add details to the question by [edit]ing it, don't use comments for that).

Comment: Thank you for the Stackoverflow tip! You seem to be right, when I intentionally disable SetProcessDpiAwareness everything becomes fuzzy, but the right size (I'll add this to the question). Also, it appears that it occurs both with PyCharm and Terminal now too on my laptop, which is a bit peculiar.

Comment: @musicamante should I report this to PyQt's github? It seems like a bug of some sort. (I'm sorry, I'm not sure how to tag properly, otherwise I'd @ you in my question's answer). Still new to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue.

The sizing becomes weirdly large ONLY when I'm running PyQt6-Qt6==6.4.1. Version 6.4.0 works perfectly fine without any scaling problems.

I've set a hard version requirement to my requirements.txt to solve the issue.

The reason it worked in terminal and not PyCharm is because of my terminal's (err, my global) outdated installation.